# Is a there way to config an ALB for two clusters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, amazon-elb

I'm trying to set up a single loadbalancer in AWS for two clusters in a the same VPC, is that possible?

Because it only provides one DNS name which sometimes routes to cluster A and sometimes cluster B.

Comment: These 2 clusters do different things presumably. Why do you not want 2 ALBs?

Comment: You can associate each cluster to its own target group, and define listener rules to dispatch requests to either cluster. Edit: technically you would associate each service running on a cluster to a target group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can defintely use a single LB in front of multiple clusters  which are in different AZ .

> one DNS name which sometimes routes to cluster A and sometimes cluster B.

Its true that ALB exposes a single hostname which routes to cluster A and sometimes cluster B because this is what load balancing means, balancing load/raffic to different clusters, but this is happening because right now may be both the clusters are registered to a single target group.

However, you can register  cluster 1 in target group 1  and another cluster 2 in target group 2. ALB allows you to route request to [different target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html) based on ;-

- path in url
- hostname
- query string
- source IP condition
- HTTP header
- host header

so for example in the case of URL in path condition [www.example.com/a](http://www.example.com/a) will got to target group one means cluster 1 and for [www.example.com/b](http://www.example.com/b) request will got to target group 2 means cluster 2

Comment: You're a super hero Jatin! May Zeus be with you.

Comment: Glad to help you :)